# Not a HASH reference error received while trying to loop through array inside a hash

Tags: json, perl, hash

I've been trying to make a reddit bot which scrapes the moderator list from a given array of subreddits. So far I've only tried to use the reddit API to retrieve one single mod list (in JSON format). I've decoded it using the JSON perl module and now I'm trying to loop through it to build a mod list. Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new('RedditBot/ModScraper');
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/about/moderators.json');
my $res = $ua->request($req);


if($res->is_success){
    my $djson = decode_json($res->content);
    my @datalist = $djson->{'data'}{'children'};
    my @names;
    for(my $i=0;$i<@datalist;$i++){
            push(@names, $datalist[$i]->{'name'});
    }
    print Dumper @names;

}
else{
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
}
```

And here is the Dumped hash/array:

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1201242956',
        'name' => 'illuminatedwax',
        'id' => 't2_14nvj'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1282272786',
        'name' => 'krispykrackers',
        'id' => 't2_35gvu'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1306697593',
        'name' => 'doug3465',
        'id' => 't2_4d9s0'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1306884548',
        'name' => 'Kylde',
        'id' => 't2_q22x'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1318239301',
        'name' => 'GuitarFreak027',
        'id' => 't2_3uh1q'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1328330491',
        'name' => 'sodypop',
        'id' => 't2_39hzo'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'all'
                             ],
        'date' => '1334668866',
        'name' => 'brownboy13',
        'id' => 't2_4itnj'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1338375544',
        'name' => 'neptath',
        'id' => 't2_42sls'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1338375575',
        'name' => 'kabuliwallah',
        'id' => 't2_3wqp9'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1338375584',
        'name' => 'poop_monster',
        'id' => 't2_45a14'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1342052024',
        'name' => 'WellEndowedMod',
        'id' => 't2_66grn'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1351424249',
        'name' => 'complex_reduction',
        'id' => 't2_4y36s'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1351427857',
        'name' => 'anions',
        'id' => 't2_33ggu'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1363446597',
        'name' => 'Livyka',
        'id' => 't2_5p6ae'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1363450026',
        'name' => 'Lord_Nuke',
        'id' => 't2_4fvxr'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1363450241',
        'name' => 'redtaboo',
        'id' => 't2_3belm'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1363453699',
        'name' => 'Knowltey',
        'id' => 't2_3aadp'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789143',
        'name' => 'AutoModerator',
        'id' => 't2_6l4z3'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789148',
        'name' => 'thejellydude',
        'id' => 't2_3g59f'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'config',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789172',
        'name' => 'DuckDragon',
        'id' => 't2_52snu'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789188',
        'name' => 'Kensin',
        'id' => 't2_4nbrl'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789200',
        'name' => 'cahman',
        'id' => 't2_6y7ld'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789214',
        'name' => 'topodan',
        'id' => 't2_8nisz'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789225',
        'name' => 'ADHD_orc',
        'id' => 't2_5dwik'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789236',
        'name' => 'all_my_rage',
        'id' => 't2_6z81j'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'mail'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789251',
        'name' => 'funny_mod',
        'id' => 't2_5qz0k'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789269',
        'name' => 'benologist',
        'id' => 't2_358ts'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789281',
        'name' => 'dizzie131',
        'id' => 't2_bb3q5'
      },
      {
        'mod_permissions' => [
                               'wiki',
                               'posts',
                               'access',
                               'mail',
                               'flair'
                             ],
        'date' => '1401789298',
        'name' => 'KimJongUnchained',
        'id' => 't2_b9c4n'
      }
    ];
```

My error is:

```
Not a HASH reference at modscraper.pl line 15.
```

I know this is probably something trivial, but I'm a pretty new Perl programmer and haven't done much JSON/Networking work before. Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, line 15 is the for loop and the dumped array/hash is @datalist.

Comment: Can it be that $datalist[$i] is a hash? try $datalist[$i]{'name'}

Comment: $datalist[$i] is a hash, however the error is on line 15, the for loop. That said, I have tried $datalist[$i]{'name'} but nothing happens.

Comment: $datalist[$i] is an array, not an hash.
If you want a hash you need to use '%' instead of '@'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the dumped hash/array value that you have given is a array reference, so the datalist variable should be defined as a array ref, so the code line for that should be changed to:

```
my $datalist = $djson->{'data'}{'children'};
```

also, we have to change the for loop code because now datalist is a array ref, so you can change the for loop code to this:

```
for(my $i=0;$i<@$datalist;$i++){
    push(@names, $datalist->[$i]->{'name'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this clarified everything! I've just ran the code again and looked up some information on array refs, and the vector was filled with the info I wanted.